# Auto complete result set with %(wildcard chars) not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, autosuggest

the function call as follow ,

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
    url: suggest_url,
    minChars:3,
    maxItemsToShow:50,
    matchInside: true,
    matchCase:0,
    onItemSelect: function(item) {
        do_search(true);
    }
});
```

when tries "Cotton" query shows  following results with percentage values as well, but not coming to suggestions.

```
100% RAYON COTTON
100% Rayon cotton
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
```

When try with "COTTONCANDY" it displays all the suggestions.

```
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
NOVA COTTONCANDY
```

Problem here the **precentage sign(%)** , is there any way to get **names with percentages(or any other wildcard characters) to the suggestion list**?

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing in the current autocomplete API that would prevent this. Since `%` is an SQL wildcard, as well as a character used in URL encoding, I'd look at other points in your app. Also, you don't specify which version of jQuery UI you're using for autocomplete, but `minChars` is an older attribute. If you are in fact using an older version, consider upgrading and seeing if that solves your problem.

Comment: @Palpatim : what you are pointing is correct, the jquery UI library is an older version. I managed to sort that with php as answered below Thx

Answer (score 0):

This code line helped to get the suggestion list.

```
$name = preg_replace("#%#", "pct", $name);
```

cheers